# return null from select in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I'm using oracle database 12c in windows x64.
I imported an oracle database(from a .dmp file). The detail information view from oracle sql developer shows:

```
NUM_ROWS:74524900; BLOCKS:1356877; AVG_ROW_LEN:126; SAMPLE_SIZE:2000
```

However, when I try to run sql commands:

```
select * from <table_name> where rownum<=10;
```

or `select * from <table_name>;`

I got nothing returned. And the status show the retrieved number of rows: 0 ("提取的所有行：0").

I also try to run these commands in cmd, and failed again. The returned information is "No row is selected" (未选定行).

Please help. Thx!

Comment: I guess I failed in importing. As it works, if I create a new table. So the problem is why the detail information exists, and it takes two minutes to run the select command.

Comment: Two minutes to run the select command: May be caused by the fact that your <table_name>'s segment has grown to an enormous size, so full table scanning it (only to see that there are no rows in it) may take those 2 minutes.

The detail information from SQL Developer seems to be based on the Oracle dictionary info. The table, clearly, was analyzed in the past, and the statistics have been imported ... but the table's data haven't.

And why there are no data? Now, I'd like to know that, too. :-(

Comment: There may be multiple reason as to why there are no data in your table. Two come to my mind at this instant: (1) VPD policy kicked in while querying the table, (2) Something (a trigger maybe) deleted your table's data after they have been imported.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks nop77svk. This is because I failed to import the table. A close look at the import log file show that the table failed to pass 8192 extension (oracle error 1653). A drawback of 42679603 lines occurred.

I guess I may need to import the table one by one. And turn on the autoextend option of the tablespaces.

Thanks anyway.